# Grunticon embed not working

Tags: gruntjs

I need help making the data-grunticon-embed option work when using Grunticon.
I think all is set up correctly - indeed grunticon is working, except for when I try to embed the icons in my markup using the data-grunticon-embed. It just won't work.

How to tell if there is something I'm doing wrong? No console log error!

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Yes, I was using "data-grunticon-embed" as a class :|

Comment: Any update upon this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To enable grunticon svg embeding:

1. Add `enhanceSVG: true` to grunticon options inside gruntfile.js
2. Replace grunticon.loader code in your `<script>` tag with the new one - generated after adding `enhanceSVG: true` option
3. Add `grunticon.svgLoadedCallback` to your grunticon call, as below:

   ```
   grunticon(["icons.data.svg.css", "icons.data.png.css",
   "icons.fallback.css"], grunticon.svgLoadedCallback );
   ```

Further explanation you will find here: https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon in "Version 2.0 is out - Here's What's New!" section